Is there another way to prove this Integral equality?
There is a problem from my Calculus textbook that:
Prove that: For $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ integrable on [a,b], $n\ge0$, $$f(b)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}+{1\over n!}\int_{a}^bf^{(n+1)}(t)(b-t)^{n}dt$$
My solution:I try to transform the RHS to LHS
$$\begin{align*}
RHS&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}+{1\over n!}\int_{a}^bf^{(n+1)}(t)(b-t)^{n}dt\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}+{1\over n!}\int_{a}^b(b-t)^{n}d(f^{(n)}(t))\\
&\stackrel{\text{int. by parts}}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}+\frac{(b-t)^nf^{(n)}(t)}{n!}|_a^{b}+{1\over (n-1)!}\int_{a}^bf^{(n)}(t)(b-t)^{n-1}dt\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}-\frac{(b-a)^nf^{(n)}(a)}{n!}+{1\over (n-1)!}\int_{a}^bf^{(n)}(t)(b-t)^{n-1}dt\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}+{1\over (n-1)!}\int_{a}^bf^{(n)}(t)(b-t)^{n-1}dt\\
&\,\,\vdots\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^0\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}+{1\over 0!}\int_{a}^bf^{'}(t)(b-t)^{0}dt \\
&=f(a)+f(b)-f(a)\\
&= f(b) = LHS
\end{align*}$$
$\Rightarrow Q.E.D$
However, I want to directly go from LHS to RHS, so from $f(b)$, I apply Taylor series so that I can have:
$$f(b)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}+R_{n}(c)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^{k}+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(b-a)^{n+1}\, (a<c<b)$$
which means I have to prove that $$\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(b-a)^{n+1}={1\over n!}\int_{a}^bf^{(n+1)}(t)(b-t)^{n}dt$$$$\iff\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)}(b-a)^{n+1}=\int_{a}^bf^{(n+1)}(t)(b-t)^{n}dt$$
In order to do that, I think of using the definition of definite integral
$$\int_{a}^bf(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x_{i}\;(where\,\Delta x_{i}\,is\,partition\,method\,of\,[a,b]\,and\,x_{i}^{*}\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]\subset[a,b])$$
From here, I kinda wonder whether I can put the $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}$ or link the definite integral definition to what I need to prove. Please clarify me what I should or whether it is possible to prove LHS to RHS instead of vice versa

That is Taylor's theorem with the integral remainder. You can find a proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder

thx so much, I really appreciate that
